# Transition partition arcs back to original angles

Tags: d3.js, transition

How can I transition arc angles, initially defined by `d3.svg.arc()`, back to their original values when using `d3.layout.partition`?

I am trying to store the initial startAngle and endAngle values `d.x` and `d.dx` somewhere so that I can transition back to them at a later state. However, I do not know:

1. At what point `d.x` and `d.dx` are initialized, whether in `d3.svg.arc()` or when the arc paths are actually appended.
2. How to bind `d.x` and `d.dx` to the elements when I am using a partition to render them.

Normally I might bind the initial startAngle and endAngle to the elements with `datum()`. I believe I am looking for something similar to:

```
selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
    return partition.values({
            'initialStart': d.x,
            'initialEnd': d.dx
        }).nodes(d)
    });
```

Comment: It sounds like in principle this would be very similar to [transitioning pie charts](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) where you save the original value in a separate attribute. The attributes are set when the layout is run, i.e. independent of any operation to append elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Perfect, this is what I was looking for. A crucial step was retrieving the stored variable from within the tween. Wish my searches would have revealed that example, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle this is the same as [transitioning pie charts](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410), where you need a custom tween function to get the animation right. For this it is necessary to save the original value in a separate attribute -- in your case you can do the same thing.

Attributes are set when the layout is run; this is completely independent of the rendering and appending elements to the DOM.